# Clickable Sub Header in ionic v1

Tags: ionic-framework

I have hader in ion-view like

```
ion-view(title='{{review_type}} reviews',ng-cache="false",cache-view='false')
  wta-nav-action-right(icon='icon-white-plus', action='reviewAdd')
  ion-content
    review-empty-list(ng-show='!reviews.length')
    section(style="margin-top:10px")
      wta-review(ng-repeat='review in reviews')
      infinite-scroll(items='reviews', query='query')
```

I converted this to two line header like this
[image: I am trying to convert “Blueberry Wine” into hyperlink so that by clicking on this user can navigate to respective Page…]

I am trying to convert “Blueberry Wine” into hyperlink so that by clicking on this user can navigate to respective Page…

I tried but `ng-click` event is not triggered.
I put `span` tag inside the `ion-view title` and give `ng-click` attribute to that `span` but still event is not triggered.

```
ion-view(title='<span class="header",ng-click="clickable()">{{review_type}} reviews</span>,'ng-cache="false",cache-view='false')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done this by adding this .. here is code pan link https://codepen.io/calendee/pen/bLJcD

```
ion-view(title='{{review_type}} reviews',ng-cache="false",cache-view='false')
  wta-nav-action-right(icon='icon-white-plus', action='reviewAdd')
  ion-content
    section
      nav
        a.col.text-center.center(style="background-color: #f0483d;color: white;padding: 10px 0")
          h4(style="color :white") Winery Name
    review-empty-list(ng-show='!reviews.length')
    section(style="margin-top:10px")
      wta-review(ng-repeat='review in reviews')
      infinite-scroll(items='reviews', query='query')
```